# Check if NSMutableArray contains a given value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains `String` values. I have a String variable and I want to check if it is contained in the array or not.

I tried using `.contains()` with String but it say:

> Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type...

```
var mutableArray = NSMutableArray()  // ["abc", "123"]
var string = "abc"

mutableArray.contains("abc") {       // above error in this line

}
```

Comment: Please show your code! And why are you not using a native Swift array?

Comment: Because I need to utilise the way it indexes the array and that I can manipulate it on the go. Edited my question

Comment: why dont you take a String array like `var mutableArray = [String]` and than just check as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to check element existence in `NSMutableArray`. i.e

```
if mutableArray.contains("abc")  
    print("found")  
else  
    print("not found")
```

or

```
if contains(mutableArray, "abc")   
    print("found")
```

or

```
if mutableArray.indexOfObject("abc") != NSNotFound
  print("found")
```

> If we want to check existence of element according of version of
>   **swift**

**Swift1**

```
if let index = find(mutableArray, "abc")  
    print(index)
```

**Swift 2**

```
if let index = mutableArray.indexOf("abc")  
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do still not understand why you cannot use a native Swift array, but okay.

Two possible solutions are to either use

```
let contains = mutableArray.contains { $0 as? String == "abc" }
```

or

```
let contains = mutableArray.containsObject("abc")
```

or

```
let contains = mutableArray.indexOfObject("abc") != NSNotFound
```

If you would use a native array you could simply do

```
var array = ["123", "abc"]
let contains = array.contains("abc")
```